Air delivery rate for BLDC motor fan
I have a BLDC motor fan whose speed (in RPM) and dimensions are known. How can I calculate the air delivery rate of the fan at a particular speed? I want the formulae for knowing how much air is delivered by the fan.

I observe two concerns here: 1. fans are fluid mechanics, mechanical engineering, or physics, not electronics -- it would be on-topic to ask about the fan motor, or how a fan might be used for thermal management of an electronic system, but the fan in and of itself is not on-topic. (This is not the reason for which this question was closed, but this reason also has not been addressed by the edit.)


Fluid mechanics problems are notoriously complicated. Even given exact dimensions and shape of your fan blade, housing, and its environment (back pressure, etc.), we can at best give only an approximate figure. (Providing a representation of the blade would address the specific reason for which this question was closed, but not the above reason.)


Calculating air delivery against fan speed is tricky fluid dynamics.
At base though, air volume per unit time is proportional to fan speed (in the operational region of the fan).  So you usually get a measurement at a particular speed (or read it in the datasheet), and calculate pro-rata.
Have a look at for fan laws for more information.
Here's a blog post about it from a fan company which should help understand it.
